# Pre Populating Paypal amount through an email link

Tags: php, email, paypal

I am creating a PHP form which takes the customer's information and the amount they want to spend and when the submit button is hit the details are sent to my email address.

This is where I have the problem. I want to then send them a link to the PayPal account to complete the purchase. However I want the amount to be pre-populated based on the amount they selected from the forum.

Simply, can this be done?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to see examples of what you are talking about. Additionally, it might help to know if you are using a paypal button or one you generate and whether you use Payments Standard or Pro.

Comment: Additionally, have you tried going into your account and just creating a donate button there? It might be possible to create one with a text field for the amount, and see how it sends the data to PayPal, then emulate that.

Comment: That is the forum and checkboxes for the amount. However I cant make the submit button send the information to me because its handling the paypal side of things. Im looking to take those details and send an email to the person with the paypal link which already has the amount they selected generated.

Comment: That looks like the right stuff; why not just send your users a link to that form?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the action parameter of the form from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to www.someurl.com/page-that-you-can-edit.php

You then need to code your script to email you whatever information you want, and then silently redirect the buyer to PayPal (you do this by setting the header) with the appropriate paypal variables:  `cmd=_donations&business=yourpaypal@email.com&amount=xx.xx&item_name=your items name&[any other website payment standard variables ]`